# Tree traversal falls into infinite loop (with huffman algorithm implementation)

Tags: c++, binary-tree, huffman-code, tree-traversal

I am trying implementing the huffman algorithm following the steps described in this tutorial: https://www.programiz.com/dsa/huffman-coding, and so far I got this code:

```
void encode(string filename) {
  List<HuffmanNode> priorityQueue;
  List<Node<HuffmanNode>> encodeList;
  BinaryTree<HuffmanNode> toEncode;
  //Map<char, string> encodeTable;

  fstream input;
  input.open(filename, ios_base::in);
  if (input.is_open()) {
    char c;
    while (!input.eof()) {
      input.get(c);

      HuffmanNode node;
      node.data = c;
      node.frequency = 1;

      int pos = priorityQueue.find(node);
      if(pos) {
        HuffmanNode value = priorityQueue.get(pos)->getData();
        value++;
        priorityQueue.update(pos, value);
      } else {
        priorityQueue.insert(node);
      }
    }
  }
  input.close();

  priorityQueue.sort();

  for(int i=1; i<=priorityQueue.size(); i++)
    encodeList.insert( priorityQueue.get(i) );

  while(encodeList.size() > 1) {
    Node<HuffmanNode> * left = new Node<HuffmanNode>(encodeList.get(1)->getData());
    Node<HuffmanNode> * right = new Node<HuffmanNode>(encodeList.get(2)->getData());

    HuffmanNode z;
    z.data = 0;
    z.frequency = left->getData().frequency + right->getData().frequency;

    Node<HuffmanNode> z_node;
    z_node.setData(z);
    z_node.setPrevious(left);
    z_node.setNext(right);

    encodeList.remove(1);
    encodeList.remove(1);

    encodeList.insert(z_node);
  }

  Node<HuffmanNode> node_root = encodeList.get(1)->getData();
  toEncode.setRoot(&node_root);
}
```

full code for the `main.cpp` here: https://pastebin.com/Uw5g9s7j.

When I try run this, the program read the bytes from the file, group each character by frequency and order the list, but when I try generate the huffman tree, I am unable to traverse this tree, always falling into a infinte loop (the method get stuck in the nodes containing the 2 first items from the priorityQueue above).

I tried the tree class with `BinaryTree<int>`, and everything works fine in this case, but with the code above the issue happens. The code for the tree is this (in the code, `previous` == `left` and `next` == `right` - I am using here the same `Node` class already implemented for my `List` class): https://pastebin.com/ZKLjuBc8.

The code for the `List` used in this example is: https://pastebin.com/Dprh1Pfa. And the code for the `Node` class used for both the `List` and the `BinaryTree` classes is: https://pastebin.com/ATLvYyft. Anyone can tell me what I am missing here? What I am getting wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I have tried a version using only c++ stl (with no custom List or BinaryTree implementations),but the same problem happened. The code is that: https://pastebin.com/q0wrVYBB.

Comment: There are more appropriate sites than pastebin.com for code, as https://godbolt.org/ , https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/, https://ideone.com/ , https://www.onlinegdb.com/ (handle project (multi-files))...

Comment: I have tried the first one, godbold: https://godbolt.org/z/ff7doPhq5

Comment: Stop `using namespace std;`, especially not 4 times. Get rid of `Node` and `List` and use the existing containers from the STL. That removes about one third of code likely to have bugs.

Comment: List::remove leaks the node if `index == 1`

Comment: The `delete`s in your destructors cause it to crash. If I remove those, permitting memory leakage, then it runs and does not enter an infinite loop. You need to test those classes thoroughly before trying to use them. By the way, you do know that indices in C start at zero, right?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow How `List::remove` leaks the node for `index == 1`? the first `if` do not handle this case?

Comment: @MarkAdler I remove the `delete` in the destructors (and the destructors themselves), but I keep getting the same issue. About the index, the `get` method in the code are built to use values from 1 to list.size(), is it right?

Comment: The first `if` handles a list of size 1, which also leaks.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow What could be fix that?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: #include <list>

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow But if I couldn't do that? What could be the alternative?

Comment: Tip: implement `operator <=>` for `HuffmanNode`

Comment: Still a mess. The first thing I noticed though is that `inOrder()` will recurse infinitely. There is no escape. It needs `if (node == nullptr) return;`.

Answer (score 0):

Too many things to mention as comments so I'm using an answer, sorry:

So going top to bottom through the code:

1. Why are you defining all methods outside the class? That just makes the code so much harder to read and is much more work to type.
2. Node::Node()

NULL is C code, use nullptr. And why not use member initialization in the class?

```
class Node {
private:
  T data{};
  Node * previous{nullptr};
  Node * next{nullptr};
...
```

3. Node::Node(Node * node) {

What is that supposed to be? You create a new node, copy the value and attach it to the existing list of Nodes like a Remora.

Is this supposed to replace the old Node? Be a move constructor?

4. Node::Node(T data)

Write

```
Node<T>::Node(T data_ = T{}) : data{data_} { }
```

and remove the default constructor. The member initialization from (1) initializes the remaining members.

5. Node::Node(T data, Node * previous, Node * next)

Again creating a Remora. This is not inserting into an existing list.

6. T Node::getData(), void Node::setData(T value)

If everyone can get and set `data` then just make it public. That will also mean it will work with `cons Node<T>`. Your functions are not const correct because you lack all the `const` versions.

7. Same for `previous` and `next`. But those should actually do something when you set the member. The node you point to should point back to you or made to do so:

   void Node::setPrevious(Node * previous) {
   // don't break an existing list
   assert(this->previous == nullptr);
   assert(previous->next == nullptr);
   this->previous = previous;
   previous->next = this;
   }
8. Think about the copy and move constructors and assignment.

Follow the rule of 0/3/5: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three . This goes for Node, List, ... all the classes.

9. List::List()

Simpler to use

```
  Node<T> * first{nullptr};
```

10. List::~List()

You are deleting the elements of the list front to back, each time traversing the list from front till you find index number `i`. While horrible inefficient the front nodes have also already been deleted. This is "use after free".

11. void List::insert(T data)

```
this->first = new Node<T>();
this->first->setData(data);
```

just write

```
first = new Node<T>(data);
```

And if insert will append to the tail of the list then why not keep track of the tail so the insert runs in O(1)?

12. void List::update(int index, T data)

If you need access to a list by index that is a clear sign that you are using the wrong data structure. Use a vector, not a list, if you need this.

13. void List::remove(int index)

As mentioned in comments there are 2 memory leaks here. Also `aux->next->previous` still points at the deleted aux likely causing "use after free" later on.

14. int List::size()

Nothing wrong here, that's a first. But if you need this frequently you could keep track of the size of the list in the List class.

15. Node * List::get(int index)

Nothing wrong except the place where you use this has already freed the nodes so this blows up. Missing the `const` counterpart. And again a strong indication you should be using a vector.

16. void List::set(int index, Node * value)

What's this supposed to do? Replace the n-th node in a list with a new node? Insert the node at a specific position? What it actually does it follow the list for `index` steps and then assign the local variable `aux` the value of `value`. Meaning it does absolutely nothing, slowly.

17. int List::find(T data)

Why return an index? Why not return a reference to the node? Also const and non-const version.

18. void List::sort()

This code looks like a bubblesort. Assuming it wasn't totaly broken by all the previous issues, would be O(n^4). I'm assuming the `if(jMin != i)` is supposed to swap the two elements in the list. Well, it's not.

I'm giving up now. This is all just the support classes to implement the `BinaryTree`, which itself is just support. 565 lines of code before you even start with your actual problem and it seems a lot of it broken one way or another. None of it can work with the state `Node` and `List` are in. Especially with copy construction / copy assignment of lists.

Comment: I just tried a version using only c++ stl (https://pastebin.com/q0wrVYBB), and the same problem happens. Probably the real issue is none of the described in the answer? (Like I said before, I have tested the List/BinaryTree implementation with `List<int>` and `BinaryTree<int>`, and everything worked fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how you tested but that code is just full of UB.

Comment: `HuffmanNode left = priorityQueue.front();` makes a copy of the node. `z.left = &left;` then stores the address of the local variable in the new node. Same for `right`. At the end of the `while` loop building the tree it all becomes invalid and UB.

Comment: Issue 8: Think about copy/move constructor / assignment operator. At a minimum `= delete` them so the compiler fails when you try to use one accidentally.

Comment: here an example where the code just works: https://godbolt.org/z/fa7ca9Gno.

Comment: You only call 3 list functions: `insert`, which is just inefficient but not wrong, `get` which is fine outside the `~List()` and `~List()` which you emptied so it no longer crashes. You are leaking 14 blocks of memory, 336 bytes. So yeah, that works. Removing the `delete`s avoids the UB the `~List` had.

Comment: I now realize the Node constructors for points 3 and 5 are for Trees. In which case they probably make sense. You seem to be using `Node<T>` for both a single linked list (which makes them very lopsided trees) and the binary tree. That reuse makes the code rather confusing. Single linked lists should only have a `next` pointer and binary trees commonly have `left` and `right` instead of `previous` and `next`. So scratch 3 and 5 from the list above.

Comment: this version almost work: https://godbolt.org/z/fo5hEMcTh (and using HuffmanNode instead of tree). But only the tree first elements from the list returned by the method `inOrder` are show.

Comment: never mind, I just create separate Node classes for the List and the BinaryTree, and now everything works.

Comment: I don't know how you're even compiling your code. That last version (godbolt.org/z/fo5hEMcTh) _almost_ compiled, with only two errors. (Much better than previous versions.) I corrected those, which needed `<T>` after `Node` on lines 313 and 330. Then it was able to run, but that ran afoul in `inOrder()`, trying to access something that no longer exists.